# Invalid Property on Extended FIORI Application

Tags: odata, sap-fiori

We are implementing an extended My Quotations Fiori application. Basically we added a new field Sales Order to the UI. The field fetches data from the backend so we also extended our OData service. On the first view, we can successfully call the data. But whenever we navigate to the next view via clicking Edit button, we get this error

Property 'SalesOrder' is invalid. Choose "Refresh" to update pricing information.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Here is our custom code for S3 view controller. We used WEB IDE to create the extension btw. The second function is for the creation of the Sales Order whenever the quotation has no associated SO tied to it.

```
manageSalesOrderFields: function() {
    alert("manageSalesOrderFields");
    var salesOrderId = "";

    // hide all fields
    view.byId("salesOrderLabel").setVisible(false);
    view.byId("salesOrderText").setVisible(false);
    view.byId("triggerSalesOrderLabel").setVisible(false);
    view.byId("triggerSalesOrderButton").setVisible(false);

    $.getJSON("/sap/opu/odata/sap/zlord_my_quotation_srv/QuotationHeaderSet('" + quotationId + "')",
        function(data) {
            alert("enterHere");
            salesOrderId = data.d.SalesOrder;
            alert(salesOrderId);
            if (salesOrderId !== "" ){
                view.byId("salesOrderLabel").setVisible(true);
                view.byId("salesOrderText").setVisible(true);
            }else{
                view.byId("triggerSalesOrderLabel").setVisible(true);
                view.byId("triggerSalesOrderButton").setVisible(true);
                view.byId("triggerSalesOrderButton").detachPress(sap.ui.controller("...").createSalesOrder);
                view.byId("triggerSalesOrderButton").attachPress(sap.ui.controller("...").createSalesOrder);
            }
        });
},
createSalesOrder: function () {
    var createSalesOrderDialog = new sap.m.Dialog("createSoDialog", {
        title: "Create Sales Order",
        icon: "sap-icon://sales-order",
        content: [
            new sap.ui.core.HTML({content:"<p style='margin:0;padding: 16px;'>Do want to create a sales order?</p>"})
        ],
        buttons:[
            new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Yes",
                press : function() {
                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel('/sap/opu/odata/sap/zlord_my_quotation_srv/');
                    var oParameter = {
                        "QuotationID" : quotationId
                    };
                    oModel.callFunction('/CreateSalesOrder', 'GET', oParameter, 'null',
                        function (oData, oResponse) {
                            var responseMessage = JSON.stringify(oResponse.body);
                            var responseMessageStart = responseMessage.search('<d:Message>');
                            var responseMessageEnd = responseMessage.search('</d:Message>');
                            responseMessage = responseMessage.substring(responseMessageStart + 11, responseMessageEnd);

                            //show MessageToast
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show(responseMessage);
                            view.byId("triggerSalesOrderLabel").setVisible(false);
                            view.byId("triggerSalesOrderButton").setVisible(false);

                            console.log(responseMessage);
                        },
                        function (oError) {
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show('Error - see log');
                            console.log(oError);
                        }
                    );
                    createSalesOrderDialog.close();
                    createSalesOrderDialog.destroy();
                }
            }),
            new sap.m.Button({
                text: "No",
                press : function() {
                    createSalesOrderDialog.close();
                    createSalesOrderDialog.destroy();
                }
            })
        ]
    });
    createSalesOrderDialog.open();
}
```

We didn't edit anything on the next view controller (CreateQuotations.view.controller.js) since it is not relevant for us to show the SO number on that view.

Comment: Can you add the code? 
are you setting SalesOrder as property of any SAPUI5 control?

Comment: Hi Sunil! I have edited the my post to reflect our code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of this line:

```
salesOrderId = data.d.SalesOrder;
```

**How to fix?**

Step 1 : Check results first in network tab for the call:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/zlord_my_quotation_srv/QuotationHeaderSet('quotationIdId');
```

Sample:

[image]

Step 2: Check the results hierarchy . How?

`console.log(data); //in success call`

Step 3: Then restructure your statement to something like this

`salesOrderId = data.d.results[0].SalesOrder;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sunil, This doesn't seem to be the cause of the error. salesOrderId is fine. We could get the data for that just fine using our code. I have the alert call there and it is showing the correct sales order id. My problem is on the next view when we click edit button.